# Secure Member Login Using Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, session, session-fixation

Is storing **username** & **password** of the user in a cookie a good practice? I really want to know how big websites like (*Facebook, digg, twitter*) handle this. My code is like that:

```
<?php

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

?>
```

After every successful login i store the `$username` and the `$password` (md5) in a cookie. And regenerate the session id with `session_regenerate_id()`

---

And to authenticate the user i check if a login session exists, otherwise i authenticate the cookies.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused – are you using PHP sessions, or cookies?

If you store the data in a session `($_SESSION['username'] = 'Tom'` etc.), that data is not stored in the user cookie.

If you store the data in a separate cookie (for something like automatic login), you might want to store a different, random id instead, and look up the user id a database table.

```
autologins
----------
key (random hash)
user_id
expires
```

Comment: I authenticate the cookie, then set a session. If a session is already set i use it directly. Your autologins idea is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just an md5 is not enough, you should at least include a random 'salt' (a small random string of characters) that you store in your database.

Edit: Btw, did you store the password plain text or encrypted? That could be a bigger security risk.

Comment: Alright, i have an idea about salting.. but is it enough secure to store it in the cookie?

Comment: Stored only in MD5. but i am going to change this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice is to give the user a session ID in a cookie, either yourself or using PHP sessions. Storing the username and password hash in a cookie is still done by some sites, but I prefer the former. It allows you to give the users more control over their logins, so they can see how many sessions they have and which IP they are from, for example - see GMail for a good example.

On the subject of salts and hashing, you should store the password hashes in the database salted. Ideally the salt should be different for each user. In the event that your database is stolen or exposed, this will make it a LOT harder for an attacker to get passwords (if they all used the same salt they could generate rainbow tables for that salt, which takes a long time, but would let them then break passwords quite quickly). For security the salt should also contain some non alphanumeric characters, like %$&^.

Comment: I don't have any background about dealing with sesion ID in cookies, but the project i am working on doesn't make it necessary to give the user their ip, sessions,etc.. as you said. Thanks for the salting strategy explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Joel L's answer is a good one. The only thing I'd add is that instead of a random ID, you could add some extra information identifying the user to make it more secure.

For example, use a hash of the user's IP address and a salt, provides extra security against someone stealing or sniffing the user's security cookie.

I suspect that TWitter uses something like this, which is why you can only be permanently logged into Twitter from one computer at a time.

Comment: I concluded that associating user ip with just about anything is useless and causes a lot of problems, because on mobile networks the IP can change every minute, also many mobile devices and networks automatically use proxies without user knowing it.